# Vector fields in electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, vector-fields

Will divergence get vanished in vector fields? What is vanishing divergence in a vector field?

Comment: not for all vector fields.

Comment: Why do you think divergence gets vanished in a vector field? Presently, the question is quite vague and it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: thats his first question.

Comment: I'm asking  is there at any point that the divergence getting vanished in a vector field???

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking about. There's a definition of divergence for vector fields, and it may be zero or it may not be zero. What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, a divergence of 0 means that there is no 'source' of vector field in the infinitesimal volume that is considered. This is because divergence is a measure of flux entering and leaving. If there is no vector field 'source' (or drain), then what goes in *must* come out.

If we take region of space that has no charges, we will find that $\nabla\cdot{E}=0$. Does it mean that there is no electric field passing through the volume? No, all it says is that there are no electric field sources over the volume you are considering -- no change in flux.

If there is indeed a source charge in the infinitesimal volume of consideration, then $\nabla\cdot E=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$, that is, an electric field source is hidden in the volume, and it is causing a net change in flux.

Answer (score 1):

The statement vanishing divergence of a vector field simply means
$$ \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=0 . $$
Here $\nabla=\hat{x}\partial_x+\hat{y}\partial_y+\hat{z}\partial_z$. In this case the electric field is the vector field under consideration. This situation applies in electromagnetism when there are no charges. On the other hand, when there are charges present, the electric field is not divergence free (the divergence does not vanish). Then we have
$$ \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\rho/\epsilon_0 , $$
where $\rho$ is the electric charge density.

The magnetic field is always divergence free
$$ \nabla\cdot\mathbf{B}=0 , $$
because there are no magnetic charges.